# I need to create a select which allows freetype in html?

Tags: html, select, freetype

I'm hoping there is just an easy answer that I have missed. I just need to create a select which allows freetype in html?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really mean FreeType (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeType) or adding an option dynamically by typing it in?

Comment: as in works exactly like a select, in that I have multiple options within it but so that I can freetype over the options if needs be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you're question correctly, you can't do this with native HTML controls.

What you're looking for, I think, is something like the following jQuery plugin: http://www.jqueryplugins.com/plugin/254/ where you can either select a pre-existing entry or enter a custom value like you would via a standard input[type=text] element.

Comment: +1 for exactly answering the question. Personally, I don't like this plugin much, because user entries are not persistent (at least at runtime). Here's another approach that I prefer: http://www.billsternberger.net/jquery/dynamically-add-dropdownlist-option-using-jquery/

Comment: @Quasdunk - To be honest, I can't say I've tried the specific plugin I referenced - it was the first result in a Google search but it looked the part. I imagine this is one of those problems that have been solved many times over and each implementation has it's own pros/cons. The link you provided looks pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DoJo ComboBox](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/ComboBox.html)

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/fYs8t/