# Let users create their own custom select menu options while keeping applications defaults

Tags: php, mysql

In an application I'm working on there is a select menu which has options such as Pending, Active, Inactive. I'd like to allow users to create their own custom options to include in these menus. They should be allowed to add edit and delete their own custom options but not the system defaults. What would a good normalized mysql schema look like for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519803/i-need-to-create-a-select-which-allows-freetype-in-html/8520074) and especially at this resource: http://www.billsternberger.net/jquery/dynamically-add-dropdownlist-option-using-jquery/

It's very simple and does what you want (except for deleting, but that shouldn't be hard to implement :))

Concerning the table structure, I's suggest to have a table for the select entries that could have following fields:

```
select_id (int 11), value (varchar 255), added_by_user (int 1)
```

where `added_by_user` does not specify the user but tells if it was added by a user. 
And in the users table, you could add the field `select_id` as a foreign key.
Now you can tell, if an entry was added by a user, and if so, by which user.

That's pretty basic, but as I said, it's just one way of doing it (and the way I do it :)), and you get the idea.

//EDIT:

If you want a user to be able to have more than one entry, the entries table should, of course, contain the `users_id` as a foreign key (and not the other way around as it is in the case above):

```
select_id (int 11), value (varchar 255), added_by_user (int 1), user_id (int 11)
```

Depending on how the `user_id`s are handled (e.g. user with ID = 0 is admin or something) the `added_by_user` field might be obsolete here.

Comment: Hi, yes jquery to add to the select is pretty easy. In your table examples. What would happen if a user added multiple entries. In the user table how would it store multiple fk's of select_ids? Would it be better in the added_by_user field to store the userID? So when we query this table show the system defaults plus any where added_by_user equals the current userID?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right! In your case, you should store the `users_id` as a foreign key in the entries-table! I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Anagio And, by the way, jQuery/JavaScript is not necessary if you don't want to use it, it just makes it look a little nicer. But it also works perfectly without.

Comment: Thanks, jQuery and AJAX are my preferred methods so the page doesn't refresh.