# User created and managed menu on website

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies, menu

I frequently get requests to allow users to create a menu on my website where they can manage a list of pages they want to regularly use when on my site.  A good example would be weathernationtv.com or weather.com where the user can add or remove favorite places to a list so they can quickly click between forecasts for cities.  I found a Joomla module that appears to do this, but I don't use Joomla.  Any suggestions on scripts or ways to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: maybe take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604159/let-users-create-their-own-custom-select-menu-options-while-keeping-applications

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you: [menu-php](http://sourceforge.net/projects/menu-php/).

It lets you dynamically create menus based on the contents of the database